# How to open the page in browser at the time of uninstalling the firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to open the link when the user uninstalls the addon, so for this what i have to code and under which event.

If anybody know about this then please help me out.

Currently this is what I am doing at the time of uninstall. But `gBrowser.addTab(Website + 'uninstalled=true&token=' + uniqueguid);`  is not working over here.

```js
var UninstallObserver = {
_uninstall : false,
observe : function(subject, topic, data) {

           //===Write Code here for Delete File Uninsatll Time
           //alert("Uninstall Time Delete File");
           var Filename = "webmail";
           // Delete all template file.

try{
var pref =  Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
var finished = "";
pref.setBoolPref("myextension.install.just_installed", false);  
}
catch(e) {}


            gBrowser.addTab(Website + 'uninstalled=true&token=' + uniqueguid);
            var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

            file.initWithPath(Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService( Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path+"\\DefaultTemplate.txt");
            if ( file.exists() == true )
            {   
                var aFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance();
                if (aFile instanceof Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile)
                {                            
                    aFile.initWithPath(Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService( Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path + "\\DefaultTemplate.txt");
                    aFile.remove(false);
                }
            }           
        //=======       
  if (topic == "em-action-requested") {
    subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUpdateItem);

    if (subject.id == MY_EXTENSION_UUID)
     {

      if (data == "item-uninstalled")
      {
                    //==Delete File Whenever Uninstall          
                         //alert("When Uninatall");
                    //===========   
         data =  "item-cancel-action";
         this._uninstall = true;
      }

      if (data == "disabled")
      {
        //  alert("You are not allow to disable SysLocker.");
        this._uninstall = true;
      }

      else if (data == "item-cancel-action") 
      {
        this._uninstall = false;
      }
    }
  } 
  else if (topic == "quit-application-granted")
  {

  data =  "item-cancel-action";
    if (this._uninstall) 
    {     
      //Code here to delete registry       
    }
    this.unregister();
  }
},

register : function() {

 var observerService =
   Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].
     getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);

 observerService.addObserver(this, "em-action-requested", false);
 observerService.addObserver(this, "quit-application-granted", false);

},

unregister : function() {

  var observerService =
    Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].
      getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);

  observerService.removeObserver(this,"em-action-requested");
  observerService.removeObserver(this,"quit-application-granted");
}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) What kind of extension is this? I assume it's a regular extension requiring restart; [bootstrapped (restartless) extensions have their own uninstall notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions).

1) Per the [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Extension_Manager), the `em-action-requested` notification was replaced with a different notification in Firefox 4+, are you testing with Firefox 4 or 3.6?

2) How exactly is gBrowser.addTab "not working over here"? Does the code get to that point? Do you get any messages in the [Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console) (see that page for set up tips)? If you put your code in an XPCOM component (which is correct), you'll first have to get a reference to a browser window. See [Working with windows in chrome code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code).

Comment: Thanks Nickolay, I am able to get the uninstall event, But my problem is I am not able to execute the gBrowser.addTab working over here.

Comment: Please help me if you find any thing related to this.

Comment: @Bhavik Goyal: it looks like you didn't see the questions and suggestions under my (2). Can I clarify anything?

Comment: code is getting to that point, but it seems no execution is done for this statement, while if we code to show alert then alert is shown before an after that point.    Also i have tried calling the request using some API, but that has also been not get. Moreover I have also tried using  openUILink(Website + "unistall=true&token=" + encodeURIComponent(uniqueguid), "a", false, true); That is the function for utilityoverlay. But that also not working. Thanks

Comment: So is this code running in an overlay for chrome://browser/content/browser.xul? That's not a good solution, since the code will run in every window. // Does |gBrowser.addTab("http://example.com/")| work in that context? What if you run it via setTimeout or from the top-level script? You didn't say anything about the Error Console. Did you get it set up and check it for messages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the em-action-requested topic is posted to observers until the extension is actually uninstalled, which happens on restart (assuming it is not a restartless extension). When are you expecting the new tab to appear? I would try setting a pref when the uninstall topic is triggered and checking for that pref on startup. If it is there, you can display your tab and remove the pref.

Comment: do you think even after uninstalling the toolbar, I will be able to execute my code? If it is so .. then can you please provide me some links?

Comment: Good point. :-) Is your extension for Firefox 4+? If so, the add-on listener API has been completely changed (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#addAddonListener())).

Comment: I don't think the 'requested' notification is delayed; https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Receiving_notification_before_an_extension_is_disabled_and.2for_uninstalled seems to agree with me.